# Getting "variable is not defined" in my Knockout code

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I don't understand why the code below keeps throwing a "viewModel is undefined" error, does anyone know why?

I actually think this may be a problem with KnockoutJS, it wants the viewModel to be a property of window. It does not recognise it when it is part of a custom namespace it seems, given that as `window.viewModel` it works fine! This is my assumption from the tests I have ran. Here is what I am doing:

```
var myNamespace.fieldworker = {};

myNamespace.fieldworker.GetFields = function() {
    var viewModel = {
        people: [
        new person("Annabelle", ["Arnie", "Anders", "Apple"]),
        new person("Bertie", ["Boutros-Boutros", "Brianna", "Barbie", "Bee-bop"]),
        new person("Charles", ["Cayenne", "Cleopatra"])
    ],
        showRenderTimes: ko.observable(false)
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
```

Document.ready is invoked from a ui page (html) which goes and calls this function:

```
function Initialize(url) {
    udfurl = url;
    myNamespace.fieldworker.GetFields();
}
```

My view is working correctly, with all the stuff I need so there is no problem there, but I cannot figure out the above problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd expect it to error with `TypeError: Cannot set property 'GetFields' of undefined`. I think your reduced test case might have reduced away your actual error but added a new one.

Comment: if I did: 'var myNamespace = {};' I guess that would bring this test case back to where it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout works fine with passing it any object for the viewModel (does not have to have global scope).  However, it sounds like you likely have an element with a data-bind that references the viewModel variable directly rather than a child of it.

Here is a sample that won't work:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: items}"></ul>

<script id="itemTmpl", type="text/html">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <button data-bind="click: function() { viewModel.removeItem($data); }">Delete</button>
    </li>
</script>


$(function() {
    var viewModel = {
        items: ko.observableArray([{
            name: "Bob"},
        {
            name: "Sue"}]),
        addItem: function() {
            this.items.push({
                name: "New"
            });
        },
        removeItem: function(item) {
            this.items.remove(item);
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

So, in this case the viewModel variable does not have global scope, because it is defined in the jQuery ready function.  When, we try to use viewModel.removeItem inside the item template, then it will not work.

Comment: I dont fully understand, could you provide an example to explain?

Comment: Hence if i was to use window.viewmodel everything would work... Why has knockout.js been designed like this? or is this something do to with javascript and global variables?

Comment: If i was to do viewmodel.additem or viewmodel.deleteitem that would work right?

Comment: No, the scope in a template while doing a foreach is the item.  You can only access methods directly off of the item.  From your previous comment, global variables can be accessed from anywhere.  Typically, people use the "templateOptions" feature of the template binding to pass in additional values that they need access to.  Docs for it here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_6_passing_additional_data_to_your_template_using_